# Show informations over Markers on Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Every marker corresponds to a person on the map, so I would like to simply display the name of that person over the marker. I can currently show the name of the person by clicking on the marker, but I want to show the name without clicking. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries available to create markers with labels that can display text.  Here are a couple:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/docs/reference.html

http://sub1.econym.org.uk/gmap/elabel.htm

Using the first library, for example, you can create markers with text with code like this:

```
new StyledMarker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    styleIcon: new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.BUBBLE, {color: "FF0000", text: "Text"})
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call infowindow.open() on each one after you've built it.  I'm assuming you already know how to build and attach them to the onclick event of the marker.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });

infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

Comment: Oh I see, I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd open the infoWindow when the `'click'` event is triggered on the marker. Simply, switch out the `'click'` event for a `'mouseover'` event to achieve your expected behaviour.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) for reference (scroll down to the Events section to see a list of supported events on the markers).

Comment: Can I do it with no events? I want it to appear on the map without having to do anything.

Comment: In that case you'd have to do what @Seano666 suggested. That would open the infoWindow without any events.